# Installing MySQLdb (Python) as non-root on EC2 Ubuntu Instance

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mysql-python

I'm trying to get MySQLdb installed on an Ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance. I can get it all installed and running, but only under root (which I can't use because I'll have automated software running that can't access root but needs to access MySQL)

So my question is: How do I install MySQLdb on a remote Ubuntu instance from only the command line without using root privileges? Any help here is appreciated

Comment: With a virtualenv, like anywhere else.

Comment: you'd only need root if you want to install it in the system dirs. you can install/run whatever you want in your own home directory.